# Joined view from DataSet in C#

Tags: c#, dataset, dataview

I have a DataSet with 2 Tables. I want to set the DataSource of a grid to the joined view of those 2 tables. It looks like there is no way to do that. What I need is to not modify the DataSet nor tables on it, just to be able to return a joined view of the tables to be used in any place. For example, ComponentOne DataSet has a TableViews array with this kind of objects. Also, I need the DataSet to save changes after any entry is modified in that view (so changes in both tables need to be saved when calling DataSet.Update()).

More information:
I already programmed it using a join and a single table in the DataSet, but I need the 2 tables (header and details) to exist in the DataSet. It is: using a join in SQL side and a single table in the DataSet I am able to save changes in both tables. But I *need* the 2 tables (headers and details) to exist in the DataSet, so I need to join them after the DataSet is filled.

Thanks.

Comment: What is wrong with using a JOIN?    After changes are made to DataSet you can use the Accept changes to put updates back into the database provided you use Command Builder.  A SQL connection has four queries 1) Select 2) Delete 3) Update 4) Insert.  The command builder takes a Select query and automatically generates the other three.  For the DataSet Accept method to work you need all four queries.

Comment: I already programmed it using a join and a single table in the DataSet, but I need the 2 tables (header and details) to exist in the DataSet.

Comment: Why two tables?  The command creates a mapping between the database and the datatable(s).  So when the DataSet accept method is executed the database tables(s) are also updated.

Comment: The source tables are two, lets say Headers and Details. I want to have both of them in the DataSet and then populate the join of both tables to show them in a grid.